# Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray) which is different from the answers I've seen

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am going off of a tutorial to create a custom object detection model to recognize a logo but I've been stuck for a while. So I've tried all the solutions that I've seen on stack overflow to this problem and unfortunately it hasn't worked. I currently am having problems with my np array being a 1D array with shape (145,). I've tried using to fix its structure but it hasn't worked out for me. I tried:

train_images=np.array(train_images,dtype=object)

train_images=np.asarray(train_images)

and several other variations

Libraries:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import PIL
import tensorflow as tf
import pathlib
import pandas as pd
from PIL import IcnsImagePlugin
from PIL.ImageDraw import Draw
import glob
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.preprocessing import image 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from skimage.segmentation import mark_boundaries
```

Converts my xml files [bounding box images] to 2 csv files. One for the training images, and one for the validation images. Used Labelimg to create the bounding boxes:

```
SKIP_NEGATIVES = True
NEGATIVE_CLASS = "no_logo"


def xml_to_csv(path, skipNegatives):
    xml_list = []
    for xml_file in glob.glob(path + '/*.xml'):
        #print("XML_FILE is: "+xml_file)
        tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
        root = tree.getroot()
        if root.find('object'):           
            for member in root.findall('object'):
                bbx = member.find('bndbox')                
                xmin = round(float(bbx.find('xmin').text))
                ymin = round(float(bbx.find('ymin').text))
                xmax = round(float(bbx.find('xmax').text))
                ymax = round(float(bbx.find('ymax').text))
                label = member.find('name').text
                value = (root.find('filename').text,
                        int(root.find('size')[0].text),
                        int(root.find('size')[1].text),
                        label,
                        xmin,
                        ymin,
                        xmax,
                        ymax
                        )
                print(value)
                
                if(value[1]>0 and value[2]>0):
                  xml_list.append(value)
                  print("Value appended",end=" ")
                  print(value)


        elif not skipNegatives:
            value = (root.find('filename').text,
                        int(root.find('size')[0].text),
                        int(root.find('size')[1].text),
                        NEGATIVE_CLASS,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0
                        )
            print("Printing Value")
            print(value)

            if(value[1]>0 and value[2]>0):
              xml_list.append(value)
              print("Value appended",end=" ")
              print(value)
            else:
              print("VALUE NOT APPENDED")

    column_name = ['filename', 'width', 'height',
                   'class', 'xmin', 'ymin', 'xmax', 'ymax']

    print("Printing XML_LIST: ")
    print(xml_list)
    xml_df = pd.DataFrame(xml_list, columns=column_name)

    print("Printing xml_df")
    print(xml_df)
    return xml_df


def main():
    datasets = ['/content/drive/MyDrive/Logo_Model/train','/content/drive/MyDrive/Logo_Model/validation']

    for ds in datasets:
        image_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Images', ds)
        xml_df = xml_to_csv(image_path, SKIP_NEGATIVES)

        print(xml_df)
        xml_df.to_csv('/{}_data.csv'.format(ds), index=None)
        print('Successfully converted xml to csv.')


main()
```

Now this is where the problem begins. When train_img_arr is appended to train_images, I have a resulting shape of train_images of (145,). The same process is for the validation data.

```
num_classes = 2
classes = ["logo","no_logo"]

TRAINING_CSV_FILE = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Logo_Model/train/logo_data.csv'
TRAINING_IMAGE_DIR = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Logo_Model/train/'
training_image_records = pd.read_csv(TRAINING_CSV_FILE)

train_image_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), TRAINING_IMAGE_DIR)

train_images = []
train_targets = []
train_labels = []

for index, row in training_image_records.iterrows():
    
  (filename, width, height, class_name, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax) = row
  
  train_image_fullpath = os.path.join(train_image_path, filename)
  train_img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(train_image_fullpath, target_size=(height, width))
  train_img_arr = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(train_img)
  
  
  xmin = round(xmin/ width, 2)
  ymin = round(ymin/ height, 2)
  xmax = round(xmax/ width, 2)
  ymax = round(ymax/ height, 2)
  
  train_images.append(train_img_arr)
  train_targets.append((xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax))
  train_labels.append(classes.index(class_name))
```

sample output of train_img_arr:

```
(78, 323, 3)
(180, 235, 3)
(180, 166, 3)
(156, 311, 3)
(180, 342, 3)
(180, 197, 3)
(180, 315, 3)
(180, 297, 3)
(180, 156, 3)
(180, 190, 3)
(180, 325, 3)
(180, 227, 3)
(176, 192, 3)
(180, 235, 3)
(180, 138, 3)
(180, 222, 3)
(180, 213, 3)
```

Convert to np arrays:

```
train_images = np.array(train_images)
train_targets = np.array(train_targets)
train_labels = np.array(train_labels)

print(train_images.shape)
print(train_targets.shape)
print(train_labels.shape)
```

Output:

```
(145,)
(145, 4)
(145,)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:2: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
```

Here is the rest of my code

```
VALIDATION_CSV_FILE = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Logo_Model/validation/logo_data.csv'
VALIDATION_IMAGE_DIR = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Logo_Model/validation/'
validation_image_records = pd.read_csv(VALIDATION_CSV_FILE)

validation_image_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), VALIDATION_IMAGE_DIR)

validation_images = []
validation_targets = []
validation_labels = []

for index, row in validation_image_records.iterrows():
    
  (filename, width, height, class_name, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax) = row
  
  validation_image_fullpath = os.path.join(validation_image_path, filename)
  validation_img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(validation_image_fullpath, target_size=(height, width))
  validation_img_arr =tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(validation_img)
  
  
  xmin = round(xmin/ width, 2)
  ymin = round(ymin/ height, 2)
  xmax = round(xmax/ width, 2)
  ymax = round(ymax/ height, 2)
  
  validation_images.append(validation_img_arr)
  validation_targets.append((xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax))
  validation_labels.append(classes.index(class_name))
```

```
validation_images = np.array(validation_images)
validation_targets = np.array(validation_targets)
validation_labels = np.array(validation_labels)

print(validation_images.shape)
print(validation_targets.shape)
print(validation_labels.shape)
```

```
input_shape = (height,width,3)
input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(input_shape)

#create the base layers
base_layers = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255, name='bl_1')(input_layer)
base_layers = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', name='bl_2')(base_layers)
base_layers = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(name='bl_3')(base_layers)
base_layers = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', name='bl_4')(base_layers)
base_layers = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(name='bl_5')(base_layers)
base_layers = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', name='bl_6')(base_layers)
base_layers = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(name='bl_7')(base_layers)
base_layers = tf.keras.layers.Flatten(name='bl_8')(base_layers)

#create the classifier branch
classifier_branch = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', name='cl_1')(base_layers)
classifier_branch = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, name='cl_head')(classifier_branch)  

#create the localiser branch
locator_branch = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', name='bb_1')(base_layers)
locator_branch = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', name='bb_2')(locator_branch)
locator_branch = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu', name='bb_3')(locator_branch)
locator_branch = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='sigmoid', name='bb_head')(locator_branch)

model = tf.keras.Model(input_layer,outputs=[classifier_branch,locator_branch])

model.summary()
```

```
losses ={"cl_head":tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), "bb_head":tf.keras.losses.MSE}
model.compile(loss=losses, optimizer='Adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
trainTargets = {
    "cl_head": train_labels,
    "bb_head": train_targets
}
validationTargets = {
    "cl_head": validation_labels,
    "bb_head": validation_targets
}
```

```
history = model.fit(train_images, trainTargets,validation_data=(validation_images, validationTargets),batch_size=4,epochs=20,shuffle=True,verbose=1)
```

Comment: Check the shape of each of the arrays that you appended with `train_images.append(train_img_arr)`  Some thing is different.

Comment: `sample output of train_img_arr:` - are those the image array sizes?  If so, that's the problem and cause of the `ragged array` warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shape of the numpy array won't show up, because the shape of each image isn't fixed.

Add `tf.image.resize`, let the shape of image fixed.

```
train_img_arr = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(train_img)
train_img_arr = tf.image.resize(train_img_arr, (size1, size2))
```

If you want your input data have different shape, you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59630011/tensorflow-datasets-make-batches-with-different-shaped-data).